# Simple nested repeater example using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

So I have tried and searched far and wide but cannot get my nested repeater to work properly.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrParent" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
    <dl class="StudentTasksList">
        <dt><%# Eval("ClassCode") %></dt>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptrChild" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <dd><%# Eval("Title") %></dd>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>            
    </dl>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

C# Code

```
        private void ListTasks()
    {
        using (StudentContext syndb = new StudentContext())
        {
            using (TaskContext dbdb = new TaskContext())
            {
                // Iterate through each active Class for the current Student finding any tasks not archived for this year
                var ClassTasks = (from c in syndb.GetClasses()
                                  where c.Students.Select(y => y.StudentID).Contains(LoggedInUserID)
                                  join t in dbdb.Tasks on c.ClassCode equals t.ClassCode
                                  where !t.Archive.HasValue || t.Archive.HasValue && t.Archive.Value && t.DueDate.Value.Year == DateTime.Now.Year
                                  group c by c.ClassCode);

                rptrParent.DataSource = ClassTasks;
                rptrParent.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

So ClassCode comes from the GetClasses() method for the selected student, and Title is the name of any Titles found in the Tasks join for the current Class.  The Result I need is a list of the classes for a student with any related task titles under each of the ClassCode.  I have tried this several different ways so this may not be the best sample of what I am trying to do.  I would get great if someone could show me a LINQ C# example of a joined linq query that populates a nested repeater as I cannot find anything decent enough to work this one out.

I would also like to know how to populate an N/A in place if the class doesn't have any tasks, but I wont push my luck.

Answer (score 1):

To populate the inner repeater, you must handle the ItemDataBound event of the parent repeater like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrParent" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptrParent_ItemDataBound">
```

And in the code behind

```
protected void rptrParent_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
    RepeaterItem item = e.Item;
    if ((item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || (item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)) {
        Repeater rptrChild = (Repeater)item.FindControl("rptrChild");
        rptrChild.DataSource = DataBinder.Eval(item.DataItem, "Group");
        rptrChild.DataBind();
    }
}
```

I guess that the property of the data item you need to use as data source of the inner repeater is `Group` as you are grouping in your LINQ statement, but maybe you need to change that...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know LINQ dose not play any role in data binding. The LINQ query you have mentioned looks find and may populate data as you needed. But You have nasted Repeater so "rptrParent.DataBind();" will bind the outer most repeater only. I think you have to write ItemDataBound event for "rptrParent" and find child repeater control assign it with group you got from LINQ query.

Hope this will help you.